# Запуск приложения Android в эмуляторе

Tags: android

> application ХХХ is waiting for the debugger to attach

Вот такое предупреждение я вижу, когда запускаю приложение, созданное с помощью Eclipse. Не хотелось бы, что бы появлялось это предуперждение. Скажите, что не так? И что сделать, чтобы этого не было?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы не появлялось такого сообщения нужно в Eclipse запускать приложение не в режиме debug-а, а просто его запускать. В Eclipse если я не ошибаюсь эта кнопочка зеленая со стрелочкой

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)